# Finding the critical temperature in the zero field Ising model via renormalisation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, renormalization, phase-transition

Inspired by images such as [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MxRddFrEnPc&feature=emb_logo), I would think that one can find the critical temperature in the zero-field Ising model computationally as follows:

1. Start with any initial temperature $T$ and calculate the magnetisation $M_0$,
2. Coarse grain in blocks and calculate the magnetisation at this level $M_1$,
3. If $|M_1|>|M_0|$, $T<T_c$, otherwise $T>T_c$,
4. Choose a new value of $T$ closer to $T_c$ and run the model again,
5. Repeat the procedure until $|\Delta M|<\epsilon$, with $\epsilon$ small.

However, as this is far simpler than the Monte Carlo methods I have looked at, I suspect that this will not work. If my suspicion is correct, what am I missing?